# Xcode 5 directory not found for option

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am working on a new project, everything was fine but today I got 3 warnings and 1 error. I don't know what happened.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/MyUser/Desktop/etc...
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lout'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried removing GoogleAdMobAds and then adding it again.
I deleted the Library Search Path from Build Settings.

I worked for me but just for a time, the next time I opened xcode I got those awful errors again.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code with your question.

Comment: @Banana I don't think there is a relevant code, i opened xcode and i saw the errors.